# Can many single page hits from a variety user agents from the same VPN with the same screen resolution be hurting my search rankings?

Tags: web-crawlers, security, traffic, botattack, ddos

I am trying to clarify what is happening with the traffic on my site. Lately I am being flooded with many strange hits, mostly from US and they seem to only open 1 page or visit for few seconds.

The attached picture shows hits from 22 different IPs at once, all from same provider (cloud vpn).

During this time my income from Google AdSense is at a record low and it makes me think these bots eider click on ads or they come from Google and quickly exit the site (back to search), showing a bounce to Google and decreasing my rankings (I am aware many say this is a myth).

Google Analytics also shown me an alert that I should look into US traffic because bounce rate is out of order compared to site average.

- Is that a ddos attack ?
- An ad clicking attack ?
- A bounce rate attack ?
- Just proxies or VPN that change IP with every request ? (user agent seems a bit different thou).

On image 2 and 3 I attached activity from some similar bots, all from US and all running windows XP with same screen resolution.

- Does it look like hits from organic search drops when there are bot hits ?

[image: many bot hits from US]
[image: do organic searches go down when the bot visits persist ?]
[image: un-natural amount of bounce rate from these bots]

Comment: There is no such thing as a "bounce rate attack".   Google doesn't use bounce rate from Google Analytics as a ranking signal.   The only way that I see these hits as affecting your rankings would if they are slowing your site down.

Comment: Maybe users name it differently, but going back to google search page must be a factor. A user posted a screenshot from google search page html code, showing some back button events that seemed relevant, can't find it now.

Comment: That is "bounce back rate" which is much different than Google Analytics bounce rate.   If these users are referred from Google Search, that could be a factor.   You don't have the referrer string listed in your spreadsheet though.